# Building tensorflow taking 9+ hours and has not finished on Ubuntu and OSX

Tags: tensorflow, build, bazel

Following the guide [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source) I'm trying to build tensorflow with AVX, FMA, XLA support using bazel for my macbook, at first I tried doing it on my mac and it kept looping forever generating a bunch of warnings and as I read about it, it should've taken 15-30 minutes and I noticed that it's exceeding 1 hour so I interrupted the execution and decided to repeat the process over GCP, Ubuntu instance, I kept it running for 9 hours and surprisingly it has not finished, it just keeps running and generating warnings, that's all it does and it looks like the problem is platform independent as the same problem occurs in macos catalina and ubuntu GCP instance.

Here are the steps I followed on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install python-dev python-pip  # or python3-dev python3-pip
pip install -U --user pip six numpy wheel setuptools mock 'future>=0.17.1'
pip install -U --user keras_applications --no-deps
pip install -U --user keras_preprocessing --no-deps
wget https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/0.29.1/bazel-0.29.1-installer-linux-x86_64.sh
chmod +x bazel-0.29.1-installer-linux-x86_64.sh
./bazel-0.29.1-installer-linux-x86_64.sh --user
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git
git checkout r2.1
./configure
```

Then I followed the configuration steps and used this command for building:

```
bazel build -c opt --copt=-mavx2 --copt=-mfma --verbose_failures -k //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

Comment: Is your issue resolved now? Generally, TF build from source takes time and it is purely depend on underlying hardware. If you are facing any issues, please share details.Thanks!

Comment: It's not solved yet, I tried yesterday to build using docker and the build completed successfully however I was unable to install it, so I retried without docker, it kept running for several hours and I got an error: `C++ compilation of rule '//tensorflow/core/kernels:sparse_redu ce_op' failed (Exit 1)` which I found in the issues section on github but unfortunately without any answers, so i'm compiling gcc 9.3 and will try again since I used gcc 6.x